# Mulesoft connection timeout issue

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm getting a Connect timeout exception when I try to run a simple mule flow:

> Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Payload
>   : {NullPayload} Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
>   Element               : /getunitedflightsFlow/processors/0 @
>   getunitedflights:getunitedflights.xml:15 (Get Flights Requests)

### Element XML           :

> Root Exception stack trace: java.net.ConnectException: Connect timeout
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.cancelled(SingleEndpointPool.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:277)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerCancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.cancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:247)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1352)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1344)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

---

Here is the Mule flow:

```
<flow name="getunitedflightsFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/home" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/essentials/united/flights" method="GET" doc:name="Get Flights Requests"/>
</flow>
```

I did some googling and it looks like a proxy/firewall issue, I tried adding the proxy settings under preferences and all Native/Direct/Manual options won't work. I also added the following properties/args:

> -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.xxxx.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUsername=myfirst.mylast -Dhttps.proxyPassword=xxxxxxxxx

it doesn't work, also tried changing the proxy settings in the Http request connector itself but this doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what's going on here,
your help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the service running at /essentials/united/flights URL? Are you able to perform the GET request using Postman for example?

Comment: I'm getting a response through the URL http://ilt.mulesoft-training.com/essentials/united/flights

Comment: Did you check input payload?

Comment: No input payload, it is a simple GET call

Comment: did you fix this? i get same error:( I can execute from postamn/soapui..but not from mule..mine also simple GET call https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538226/get-call-works-for-postman-soapui-but-not-at-mule-4-1-3

Comment: for me, it turns out it's a firewall/proxy thingy, talk to your firewall team and they can open the firewall for you to make connections out side of your companies network.